# CORS issue in azure function (.NET 7, v4)

Tags: c#, angular, azure-functions, cors

I am facing CORS issue with my azure function (C#, .NET 7). I am calling it from my angular application.

But the same function i tried calling from Postman with the same body angular application tried, its working fine.

Below my Functions Program.cs

```
using Ioc.Infrastructure.Extensions; // Ensure this is the correct namespace for your extension method
using Ioc.Application.Extensions;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure;
var host = new HostBuilder()
        .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults(builder =>
        {
            builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("IocAppOrigins", policy =>
                {
                    policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200") // Replace with your client app's URL
                          .AllowAnyMethod()
                          .AllowAnyHeader();
                });
            });
        })
    .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
    {
        // This is where you add dependencies to the service collection.
        // Your custom extension method to add infrastructure services like DbContext, Repositories, etc.
        services.AddInfrastructureServices(context.Configuration);
        services.AddApplicationServices(context.Configuration);
        // You can add other services here as required.
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

Here is the function

```
    [Function("AddMember")]
    [OpenApiOperation(operationId: "addMember", tags: new[] { "member" })]
    [OpenApiRequestBody("application/json", typeof(Membership), Description = "The member details")]
    [OpenApiResponseWithBody(statusCode: HttpStatusCode.Created, contentType: "application/json", bodyType: typeof(Membership), Description = "The created member details")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseData> AddMember(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = "members")] HttpRequestData req)
    {
        
        try
        {

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

And here is my local.settings.json (which I added manually)

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
  },
  "Host": {
    "CORS": "*"
  }
}
```

And here is my Angular calling method

```
 addMembership(membership: Membership): Observable<Membership> {
        const endpoint = '/members';
        return this.http
            .post<Membership>(`${this.baseApiUrl}${endpoint}`, membership)
            .pipe(
                map((data) => new Membership(data)),
                catchError(this.handleError)
            );
    }
```

But I am still getting the error

Below the error in developer console.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:7003/api/members' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

membership.service.ts:104 Server returned code 0, error message is: Http failure response for http://localhost:7003/api/members: 0 Unknown Error

Error! Server returned code 0, error message is: Http failure response for http://localhost:7003/api/members: 0 Unknown Error

POST http://localhost:7003/api/members net::ERR_FAILED
```

I have no idea what wrong I did?

Also I am testing it locally. Application not yet deployed to cloud

Based on @Šimon Kocúrek comment I checked the preflight request in browser network tab. It says this. I have no idea why the preflight says not found even the exact url working fine from postman

[image]

And here is the second one (could be the actual call)

[image]

Below the console updates on API calls. As you can see there is call from postman and from browser

```
[2023-11-30T22:50:05.394Z] Executing HTTP request: {
[2023-11-30T22:50:05.397Z]   requestId: "2502de18-5b2d-4850-a62d-9a1daeed8ebd",
[2023-11-30T22:50:05.399Z]   method: "OPTIONS",
[2023-11-30T22:50:05.401Z]   userAgent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
[2023-11-30T22:50:05.403Z]   uri: "/api/members"
[2023-11-30T22:50:05.405Z] }
[2023-11-30T22:50:05.407Z] Executed HTTP request: {
[2023-11-30T22:50:05.409Z]   requestId: "2502de18-5b2d-4850-a62d-9a1daeed8ebd",
[2023-11-30T22:50:05.411Z]   identities: "",
[2023-11-30T22:50:05.414Z]   status: "404",
[2023-11-30T22:50:05.417Z]   duration: "12"
[2023-11-30T22:50:05.420Z] }
[2023-11-30T22:51:27.858Z] Executing HTTP request: {
[2023-11-30T22:51:27.859Z]   requestId: "93610ba4-3b51-42ca-805b-3e472aad1835",
[2023-11-30T22:51:27.859Z]   method: "POST",
[2023-11-30T22:51:27.860Z]   userAgent: "PostmanRuntime/7.35.0",
[2023-11-30T22:51:27.862Z]   uri: "/api/members"
[2023-11-30T22:51:27.863Z] }
[2023-11-30T22:51:27.991Z] Executing 'Functions.AddMember' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=5ee373f4-1782-46ce-b24b-12884d35854a)
```

[image]

Comment: have you added allow CORS on the function app in portal?

Comment: SOrry I missed to address.. I am testing it locally... FYI
Its not yet deployed to cloud

Comment: What is the response of the OPTIONS request?

Comment: Check the Postman console and see if Postman added any http headers to the request.  If so then add the same headers to the c# request.

Comment: remember that CORS rules are enforced by the browser.  Postman does not enforce CORS rules.   Show the code that has the app.UseCors() method.  (program.cs, or startup.cs)  There's a specific order for that.  Also be aware that wildcards for methods or  headers aren't allowed when sending credentials. i.e. .AllowAnyMethod()                         .AllowAnyHeader();... this would also need to be secure... so "https"... right now you are allowing http localhost: 4200  You may also need to install the CORS module in IIS: https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/iis-cors-module

Comment: @pcalkins I have it specified as localhost:4200
Also I already shared my program.cs

Comment: @jdweng I checked PM console and no headers it attaching and my functions not implemented any auth

Comment: @ŠimonKocúrek Sorry I didnt understand that completely

Comment: @SandeepThomas Browser uses (preflight) OPTIONS request to find out whether it should allow/deny the request. If you play around with it, you can probably find out what is the issue with CORS configuration on your server: https://http.dev/options

Comment: Postman Console and c# should be exactly the same.  Do you see any differences.  If postman works than c# should also work and return the same response.  What is the status code in the response?  Is it 200 OK?The error may be due to your processing of the response.

Comment: You have http localhost specified, but any JS request with credentials would need to be secure.  See here for further details on configuring... (in your case I think it'll be host.UseCors(your policy)... ):  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-8.0  To avoid accidently decreasing security by setting these headers in production you might also consider just launching a browser with web security turned off when debugging locally... (You can create a profile for that... it would then be just like Postman with no CORS rules)

Comment: @ŠimonKocúrek Thanks for that information. based on that I have updated my question with 2 screen grabs

Comment: If request for OPTIONS returns 404, it means that your server is not returning the CORS info. Maybe check the order of middlewares. CORS middleware has to be between routing and auth: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-8.0#middleware-order

Comment: @pcalkins I havent implemented any authorization

Comment: @ŠimonKocúrek That was a great information. Based on that I have got few responses in my .net console. I have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

After hours of trials and based on inputs from @ŠimonKocúrek  I am able to reach my azure function from my angular application. Sharing that details to those who ever face this situation.

Here is my local.settings.json file which I manually created at the root of the function (Which was there before)

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "PrdConnectionString": "************"
  },
  "Host": {
    "CORS": "http://localhost:4200"
  }
}
```

But what I did extra was

[image]

And program.cs as before. (Make sure cors aligns with that in local settings)

```
var host = new HostBuilder()
        .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults(builder =>
        {
            builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("IocAppOrigins", policy =>
                {
                    policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200") // Replace with your client app's URL
                          .AllowAnyMethod()
                          .AllowAnyHeader();
                });
            });
        })
        .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
        {
            // This is where you add dependencies to the service collection.
            // Your custom extension method to add infrastructure services like DbContext, Repositories, etc.
            services.AddInfrastructureServices(context.Configuration);
            services.AddApplicationServices(context.Configuration);
            // You can add other services here as required.
        })



    .Build();

host.Run();
```